# Kendo UI ListView Data URL

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

How can I change `Kendo Ui` list view datasouce dynamically. My `Kendo Ui` listview  code is

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "ASPCode/RMScheduleList.asp",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 50
            });

            $("#pager").kendoPager({
                dataSource: dataSource
            });

$("#listView").kendoListView({dataSource: dataSource,template: kendo.template($("#template").html())});
```

How can I change URL when a checkbox click ? I want when checkbox click URL should change to `ASPCode/RMScheduleList.asp?Checkbox=true`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a "**change**" event on a `checkbox`. When the checkbox triggered, you can set datasource.

**For Example;**

```
var dataSource;

$( "#myCheckbox" ).change(function() {

var checkBox = $('.myCheckbox')[0].checked;

    if(checkBox){
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: ASPCode/RMScheduleList.asp?Checkbox=true,
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 50
                });
    }
    else{
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "ASPCode/RMScheduleList.asp",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 50
                });
    }

    $("#pager").kendoPager({
        dataSource: dataSource
    });
});
```

Maybe there can be a syntax error. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the `read` object can be modified to be able to set a dynamic variable or can be placed with some logic, like this:

```
transport: {
  read: {
      url: function () {
         var url = "ASPCode/RMScheduleList.asp" + (isChecked ? "Checkbox=true" : ""));
         return url;
      },
  dataType: "json",
  },
},
```

Hope this works for you.